# Is it possible to generate a graph where one visits nodes with binary values, with respect to a sequence and all nodes values becomes same?

Tags: graph-theory

I realize that the title is messy but my problem is this.

I want to create a graph with following rules:

- Every node has a binary value {0,1}
- Every node has 2 directed edges
- When a node is visited value inside that node and connected nodes changes {0 -> 1 || 1 -> 0}

The goal is finding a node sequence where; when all nodes in the sequence visited in the given order at the end all nodes have the same value.

For example:

Think a 3 node graph, all nodes are connected with each other and selecting 1 node makes all values 1

Think another graph with nodes and edges as follows:

```
Nodes = {1,2,3,4}
Edges = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3,  
         2 -> 1, 2 -> 4, 
         3 -> 1, 3 -> 4, 
         4 -> 2, 4 -> 3 }
```

All edges have value 0 at the start

When you follow sequence S = [1,2,3,4] all values of nodes become 1

I want to find a way to generate graphs and sequences for these graphs in this way.
I couldn't be able wrap my head around it so I hope someone can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: In the three node example, if all three nodes are mutually connected, doesn't the very first iteration make all values 1?

Comment: @aschepler ah you are right i should edit this Thank you!